# Assert two HashMaps failing with assertion error

Tags: java, groovy, junit

I am trying to assert the HashMap returned from the method *getPaymentMethod()* with the HashMap *expected*.

```
public void testGetPaymentMethod() throws Exception {
    List<Map<String, Object>> paymentOptionsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> pO = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> pM = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> capam = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> preAuthDetail = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    preAuthDetail.put("sourceSystem", "ABCD");
    preAuthDetail.put("sourceLocation", "EFGH");
    preAuthDetail.put("authorizationCode", "OL_DF161216J34491");
    capam.put("paymentAmount", 850);
    capam.put("preAuthDetail", preAuthDetail);
    pM.put("capam", capam);
    pO.put("pM",pM);
    paymentOptionsList.add(pO);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    HashMap<String, Object> result = (HashMap<String, Object>) myTransformation.getPaymentMethod(paymentOptionsList,null);
    Map<String, Object> expected = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> preAuthorizationProfile = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
    Map<String, Object> source = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> amount = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    source.put("sourceSystem", "ABCD");
    source.put("sourceLocation", "EFGH");
    amount.put("amount", 850);
    amount.put("monetaryAmount", "UNITEDSTATES_DOLLAR");
    preAuthorizationProfile.put("source", source);
    preAuthorizationProfile.put("preAuthorizationId", "OL_DF161216J34491");
    preAuthorizationProfile.put("amount", amount);
    pM.clear();
    pM.put("preAuthorizationProfile", preAuthorizationProfile);
    expected.put("pM", pM);
    assertThat(result,is(expected));
}
```

But I am getting Assertion Error as follows

> Expected: is <{paymentMethod={preAuthorizationProfile={amount={amount=850, monetaryAmount=UNITEDSTATES_DOLLAR}, source={sourceSystem=ABCD, source
>   Location=EFGH}, preAuthorizationId=OL_DF161216J34491}}}>
>        but: was <{paymentMethod={preAuthorizationProfile={source={sourceSystem=ABCD, sourceLocation=EFGH}}, preAuthorizationId=OL_DF161216J34491, a
>   mount={amount=850, monetaryAmount=UNITEDSTATES_DOLLAR}}}>

Comment: The expected has a key called `amount`, while the actual has a key of `a mount` (note the space).

Comment: @JoeC I guess I copied it from the cmd prompt that's why its showing a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have taken your error message and formatted it in a way that makes the levels of your nested maps clearer.  Note how `amount` and `preAuthorizationId` are at different levels between the two maps.

```
Expected: is <
{
    paymentMethod={
        preAuthorizationProfile={
            amount={
                amount=850, 
                monetaryAmount=UNITEDSTATES_DOLLAR
            }, 
            source={
                sourceSystem=ABCD, 
                sourceLocation=EFGH
            }, 
            preAuthorizationId=OL_DF161216J34491
        }
    }
}
> but: was <
{
    paymentMethod={
        preAuthorizationProfile={
            source={
                sourceSystem=ABCD, 
                sourceLocation=EFGH
            }
        }, 
        preAuthorizationId=OL_DF161216J34491, 
        amount={
            amount=850, monetaryAmount=UNITEDSTATES_DOLLAR
        }
    }
}
>
```

May I suggest, rather than using maps of maps of maps, try to come up with classes that represent what you're trying to do.  This will make your code much more resilient and much less prone to mistakes such as these.